# How to create advertisement on Facebook with test account?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-fql

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Invalid parameter", 
"type": "FacebookApiException", 
"code": 100, 
"error_data": {
  "blame_field_specs": [
    [
      "account_id"
    ]
  ]
}, 
"error_subcode": 1359101, 
"is_transient": false, 
"error_user_title": "Add Payment Method", 
"error_user_msg": "You need to have a valid payment method associated with your ad account before you can create ads."
}
}
```

Error while creating Ads in Facebook, I am doing this for testing purpose so can't add Payment method with Ad account, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: The error message is correct. You need to have a valid payment method to be able to run ads. You can create ads that are paused and not launch them.

Comment: Do I need to add Valid Payment method in case of creating paused ads also?